# jQuery not setting textContent

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a HTML file where I created my buttons and labels with for loop. (Django project)

Then, I tried to add some functionality using JS but my buttons don't work.
My failed part is +, - and update buttons with their functionality.

I don't know whether it is correct approach or not but I tried to differentiate my buttons assigning "button name"+{{product.id}} to their IDs.

```
 <!-- start loop -->
{% for item in cart %}

<!-- assign product variable -->
{% with product=item.product %}

<br>

<div class="row mb-4 border product-item">

  <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-2 order-md-first bg-light">

    <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" width="200px" alt="Responsive image" src="{{ product.image.url }}">
    <!-- Product image -->

  </div>


  <div class="col-md-9 col-lg-10 ps-md-3 ps-lg-10">

    <a href="{{ product.get_absolute_url }}" class="text-info text-decoration-none">

      <h1 class="h5 pt-2"> {{ product.title }} </h1>

    </a>

    <div class="border">

      <div class="col border-bottom">

        <div class="row p-3">

          <div class="col-6"> Product </div>

          <div class="col-6 text-end"><span class="h6 fw-bold">$ {{ product.price|mul:item.qty}} </span></div>

        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="col">

        <div class="row p-3">

          <div class="col-12">

            <button type="button" id="qty-decrease-button{{product.id}}" data-index="{{product.id}}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm increase-button"> - </button>

            &nbsp;

            <label id = "qty-show{{product.id}}" data-index="{{product.id}}" > {{item.qty}} </label>

            &nbsp;
            
            <button type="button" id="qty-increase-button{{product.id}}" data-index="{{product.id}}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm decrease-button"> + </button>

            <br> <br>

            <button type="button" data-index="{{product.id}}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm update-button"> Update </button>

            &nbsp;

            <button type="button" data-index="{{ product.id }}" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm delete-button"> Delete </button>

          </div>

        </div>

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>

{% endwith %}

{% endfor %}
```

My JS codes at the end of this HTML code is:

```
     // Update button

  $(document).on('click', '.update-button', function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var theproductid = $(this).data('index');

    $.ajax({

      type: 'POST',
      url: '{% url "cart-update" %}',
      data: {

        product_id: $(this).data('index'),
        // product_quantity: $('#select' + theproductid + ' option:selected').text(),
        product_quantity:  $('#qty-show' + theproductid).text(),
        csrfmiddlewaretoken: "{{csrf_token}}",
        action: 'post'

      },

      success: function (json) {

        // reload page
        location.reload();

        // update cart
        document.getElementById("cart-qty").textContent = json.qty

        // update subtotal
        document.getElementById("total").textContent = json.total


      },

      error: function (xhr, errmsg, err) {


      }

    });

  })


</script>


<!-- Increment-Decrement buttons function -->
<script>


  $(document).on('click', '.increase-button', function (e) {

      var theproductid = $(this).data('index');

      var counter = $('#qty-show' + theproductid);
      x = counter.textContent;

      // e.preventDefault();

      counter.textContent = ++x;

  })

  $(document).on('click', '.decrease-button', function (e) {

      var theproductid = $(this).data('index');

      var counter = $('#qty-show' + theproductid);
      x = counter.textContent;

      // e.preventDefault();

      if (x<=1)
      {
          counter.textContent = 1;
      }
      
      else
      {
          counter.textContent = --x;
      }

  })
  
</script>
```

Here you can see rendered HTML code:
(+/-/Update buttons does not work.)

[image]

If someone can help me for making these buttons functional, I would be appreciated!

Comment: You have asked many questions without accepting answers. Please go through your questions, and if someone answered them, click the empty checkmark next to the question to mark it as accepted, to help others find the answer in the future, and give people fake internet points :)

Comment: @AndyRay I feel like you have an answer for my this question as well :)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75636251/how-to-access-django-model-using-js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`counter` is a jQuery collection, not a raw DOM element. `.textContent` is a property of raw DOM elements.

You can either access the raw DOM element, or use the jQuery API to stet text. Either do

```js
var counter = $('#qty-show' + theproductid).get(0);
```

or do

```js
x = counter.text();
...
counter.text(x++);
```